# sudo dpkg --configure dpkg: error processing default-jdk (--configure):

Tags: package-management, dpkg

```
 default-jre depends on default-jre-headless (= 1:1.7-43ubuntu3); however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.

dpkg: error processing default-jre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jdk:
 default-jdk depends on default-jre (= 1:1.7-43ubuntu3); however:
  Package default-jre is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing default-jdk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 default-jre
 default-jdk
```

How can I solve this? Actually I had another problem (([Failing package manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107783/failing-package-manager)) ) and found a solution here, but then dpkg gives above error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the same as in the other question ([Failing package manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107783/failing-package-manager)):

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

Edit: oops, sorry, you did already do that. I recommend to skip the `dpkg --configure -a` and first do `apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any `man` pages installed (often the case in docker containers as they strive to be as minimal as possible) creating the needed folder might help you further:

```bsh
mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
```

This is due to the fact that it assumes said folder to usually be there, but doesn't take care of creating it if the folder is missing.

[Source](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-java/issues/64#issuecomment-393299088)