# Upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04 -> dpkg: error processing sudo (--configure)

Tags: 13.04, sudo, dpkg

Here's the deal and reason I'm asking for your help. Last night I went on upgrading my Xubuntu 12.10 installation to 13.04, so at tty1 I run the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and everything seemed to went well except that after rebooting and when I run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg                  
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                           
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources                       
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg [933 B]           
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources                               
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en            
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en_US              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Sources
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release [40.8 kB]
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources [2,109 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en               
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources [14 B]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources [14 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources [14 B]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages [3,670 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages [2,824 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US      
Fetched 50.4 kB in 6s (7,454 B/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/373 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: error processing sudo (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on sudo; however:
  Package sudo is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 sudo
 ubuntu-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried everything I thought logical, like

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing sudo (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on sudo; however:
  Package sudo is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sudo
 ubuntu-minimal



sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/373 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing sudo (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on sudo; however:
  Package sudo is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 sudo
 ubuntu-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me, please.

Edit:

Here's some more info that could be of help for anyone. The output of

```
 apt-cache policy linux-image-generic-pae linux-generic-pae
```

is

```
linux-image-generic-pae:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.0.19.35
  Version table:
     3.8.0.19.35 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
linux-generic-pae:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.0.19.35
  Version table:
     3.8.0.19.35 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried commands posted in [this qusetion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254880/sudo-dpkg-configure-dpkg-error-processing-default-jdk-configure)  several times.

Not sure exactly, but I think it worked after a removing all install packages by:

```
sudo apt-get clean -f
```

now it is getting new updates by:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```