# I encountered a dpkg dependency issue, and how do I resolve this issue?

Tags: dpkg

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu0.7) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
lzma: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic:
 linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.36ubuntu6); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic:
 linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.36ubuntu6); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.8.8-0ubuntu6.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
lzma: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
dpkg: error processing plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.8.0.23.39); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (0.8.8-0ubuntu6.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
lzma: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
dpkg: error processing plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of casper:
 casper depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.92bubuntu55); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing casper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic
 linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
 casper
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What were you trying to install that you needed to "-f"? It seems like a conflict repository side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failing package manager?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107783/failing-package-manager)

Answer (score 2):

The initial error is "Write error: No space left on device", so your disk is full.  Free up some space.

Comment: Nice catch totally missed that.