# 16.04 LTS Update fails - Errors were encountered while processing util-linux

Tags: 16.04, updates

Recently any attempt to update my 16.04 installation fails with errors relating to util-linux. I don't seem to be able to update or install any packages. Here is the commands I tried and the results they returned.

First I ran...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

which returned...

```
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease   
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease  
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

Then ran...

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

there was no output from this command.

Next I ran...

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

which returned (I've removed blocks that repeated many times) ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 122 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service smfpd at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
udev depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
Package util-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                        A reboot is required to replace the running dbus-daemon.
Please reboot the system when convenient.
insserv: warning: script 'K01smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service smfpd at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package dbus (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on dbus; however:
Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus-x11:
dbus-x11 depends on dbus; however:
Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dbus-x11 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
gconf2 depends on dbus-x11; however:
Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
gconf2 depends on dbus-x11; however:
Package dbuNo apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
util-linux
udev
dbus
libpam-systemd:amd64
dbus-x11
gconf2
... repeated many time
gconf2
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The next command I ran was...

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which returned...

```
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease   
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease  
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
appmenu-qt5 apport apport-gtk appstream apt apt-transport-https apt-utils
base-files bsdutils console-setup console-setup-linux firefox
firefox-locale-en gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 grub-common grub-pc
grub-pc-bin grub2-common gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-libav
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
humanity-icon-theme im-config indicator-application keyboard-configuration
klibc-utils krb5-locales libappstream3 libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0
libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2
libegl1-mesa libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libfdisk1
libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgles1-mesa
libgles2-mesa libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data
libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libhogweed4 libido3-0.1-0
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libk5crypto3 libklibc libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
libmount1 libnettle6 liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0
libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp libsmartcols1 libssl1.0.0
libwayland-egl1-mesa libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libxatracker2 libxpm4 linux-firmware
linux-libc-dev mesa-vdpau-drivers mount nano ntfs-3g openssl os-prober
oxideqt-codecs-extra pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python3-apport python3-distupgrade
python3-problem-report qml-module-ubuntu-web snap-confine snapd sudo
ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk uuid-runtime webapp-container webbrowser-app
119 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 41.3 MB/187 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,237 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y       

Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk all 1:16.04.21 [9,334 B]

<Please note that I don't have the reputation to post all of the get links>

Get:98 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 appmenu-qt5 amd64 0.3.0+16.04.20151130-0ubuntu2 [95.7 kB]
Fetched 41.3 MB in 1min 58s (349 kB/s)                                         
Extract templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service smfpd at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The next command was...

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

which returned...

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
udev depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
Package util-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for systemd:
systemd depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
Package util-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Setting up dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
A reboot is required to replace the running dbus-daemon.
Please reboot the system when convenient.
insserv: warning: script 'K01smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service smfpd at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package dbus (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on dbus; however:
Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus-x11:
dbus-x11 depends on dbus; however:
Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
gconf2 depends on dbus-x11; however:
Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.

<this block repeated many times>

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
gconf2 depends on dbus-x11; however:
Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
udev
systemd
dbus
libpam-systemd:amd64
dbus-x11
gconf2
  repeated many times
gconf2
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Finally I ran...

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

which returned...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 122 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service smfpd at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
  Package util-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                        A reboot is required to replace the running dbus-daemon.
Please reboot the system when convenient.
insserv: warning: script 'K01smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service smfpd at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package dbus (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus-x11:
 dbus-x11 depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
   dpkg: error processing package dbus-x11 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on dbus-x11; however:
   Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:

<this block repeated many times>                                                                    

 gconf2 depends on dbus-x11; however:
  Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on dbus-x11; however:
  Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
Errors were encountered while processing:
util-linux
udev
dbus
libpam-systemd:amd64
dbus-x11
gconf2
  <repeated many times>
gconf2
```

Any help, suggestions, ideas or guesses would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: The answer you need is [here.](http://askubuntu.com/a/107785/225694) Be sure to perform all the steps.

Comment: It is similar but that solution didn't help in this case.

Comment: Please be more precise. What did you try and what happened when you did. Thank you for helping us help you! For instance: I issued the first x commands and received no errors but whn I tried command Y I got an error that said "blah". We can't see whats happening so you have to tell us. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Elder Geek, I've tweaked my question. I hope it is a little clearer now. The "6 not fully installed or removed" sounds interesting to me but I'm not sure how you'd find out what those 6 are.

Comment: Sorry, I've read your update and have no idea what your comment refers to.  I also don't see the results of `sudo apt-get clean` or any of the other steps recommended other than `update` and `upgrade` which are combined in step 4 of the suggested solution and are shown as steps 1 and 2 in your post. I apologize if I was unclear. Hopefully this will add some clarity.

Comment: Thanks Elder Geek. Sorry it has taken a couple of days to reply. I've updated my question with more details. I've tried all sorts of other things and suspect that the fact I can't update or install any packages at all may to be the key to the problem. Any help / ideas would be very welcome. I'm more of a coder than an OS man.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if the repeating blocks of output to `sudo apt-get autoremove` would add some clarity here. All I can say with any certainty at the moment is that [the util-linux package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=util-linux&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) appears to be unconfigured and may be the source of your problems. There's a related question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/840242/apt-get-f-install-remove-e2fsprogs-util-linux-initscripts) with no answers. I would be tempted to backup 1st, and then  try to remove and reinstall that package.

Comment: If you have an answer to this question, please post it as one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and help Elder Geek. Looks like Samsung printer drivers have a history of messing up Linux installation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the Samsung printer driver I'd loaded to sort out a neighbour's printer problems was the cause of all my problems. That will teach me for being so helpful ;-)

The clue was this line...

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

which led me to think about printers. For the record, the drivers I downloaded and installed were `UnifiedLinuxDriver_1.00.tar.gz` which fortunately included an `uninstall.sh` script.