# What should I do with a "Failed to apply Changes" when trying to upgrade packages of Kubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I tried today to upgrade some packages of by Kubuntu distribution. However, a window appeared telling me that:

Failed to Apply Changes - Découvrir
An error occurred while applying changes:

Nothing is presented in the Details. Is there something I can do to solve the problem?

Thank you

Pierre-Olivier

Comment: What is your Kubuntu version?

Comment: And what command did you run and full output please.

Comment: @Panther I think the poster used the GUI "Discover" which is Kubuntu's Software Center because of "Découvrir".

Comment: @Dk Bose My current Kubuntu version is Kubuntu 16.05.

Comment: @Panther Yes, I use the GUI "discover" for my updates.
Thank you.

Comment: open a terminal and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and post any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

@Panther I ran the commands in a terminal. The first one give the following outcome with no error:

```
Atteint:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Atteint:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                           
Atteint:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                     
Réception de:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]                                                
Réception de:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                               
Réception de:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]          
Réception de:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [67,7 kB]
Réception de:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [793 kB]                                 
Réception de:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [68,0 kB]
Réception de:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [107 kB]
Atteint:5 https://typora.io:443 linux/ InRelease                                                  
Réception de:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [142 kB]                      
Réception de:13 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [725 kB]                               
Réception de:14 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [319 kB]
Réception de:15 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [229 kB]
Réception de:16 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [634 kB]
Réception de:17 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [579 kB]
Réception de:18 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [246 kB]
Réception de:19 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [334 kB]
Réception de:20 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5 964 B]
Réception de:21 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3 328 B]
Réception de:22 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5 100 B]
4 580 ko réceptionnés en 1s (2 645 ko/s)                        
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
132 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

The second command generated a long list of things and it came up with the following errors:

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides                                                                  
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides                                                                     
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started                                                             
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2                                                                                  
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1                                                                                    
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
```

and

```
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet util-linux (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Google those errors. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/881218/16-04-lts-update-fails-errors-were-encountered-while-processing-util-linux/884130 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371619/insserv-warning-script-k07smfpd-missing-lsb-tags-and-overrides/371655

Comment: Excuse me for this long waiting.

Comment: I tried both solutions suggested in the links, but it didn't work :(
There is still those errors related to K01smfpd

Comment: You may have to file a bug report