# Dependency errors when upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, dependencies

I dragged my feet on upgrading an old computer from 12.04(?), so yesterday finally went to 14.04 successfully then today tried to go to 16.04.

The update manager (gui) failed 3/4 of the way through and said there were too many errors encountered.  I did some searching here and and found various combinations of these commands from this [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107783/failing-package-manager) for failed upgrades and tried to perform them.  The results are as follows---mostly dependency errors which makes sense as the upgrade quit mid-way.  I didn't include the output from `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, or `sudo apt-get install -f` as it resembles autoremove and I am character limited.

Is there any way to recover from this?  Thank you!

Details:

`sudo apt-get update` gives...

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

`sudo apt-get clean` gives no output

`apt-get autoremove` gives this mess:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
657 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cron (3.0pl1-128ubuntu2) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
update-rc.d: warning: stop runlevel arguments (1) do not match cron Default-Stop values (none)
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Script virtuoso-nepomuk is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package cron (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-59.3ubuntu2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Script virtuoso-nepomuk is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: warning: script 'virtuoso-nepomuk' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Script virtuoso-nepomuk is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of procps:
 procps depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package procps (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mountall:
 mountall depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mountall (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart:
 upstart depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.
 upstart depends on mountall; however:
  Package mountall is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package upstart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools-core:
 initramfs-tools-core depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-core (= 0.122ubuntu8.11); however:
  Package initramfs-tools-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brltty:
 brltty depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.40ubuntu30); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package brltty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

<   SNIP some....I am character limited   >                                                              

                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-drivers-common:
 ubuntu-drivers-common depends on udev (>= 204-0ubuntu4~); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-drivers-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up whoopsie (0.2.52.5) ...
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Script virtuoso-nepomuk is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package whoopsie (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of keyboard-configuration:
 keyboard-configuration depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.3); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.
 console-setup depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.85eubuntu12) | linux-initramfs-tool; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
  Package linux-initramfs-tool is not installed.
  Package initramfs-tools which provides linux-initramfs-tool is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 <Snipped some here, too, to save characters>                                                              

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up rsyslog (8.16.0-1ubuntu3) ...
The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Script virtuoso-nepomuk is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on console-setup; however:
  Package console-setup is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-minimal depends on initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-minimal depends on kbd; however:
  Package kbd is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-minimal depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-minimal depends on rsyslog; however:
  Package rsyslog is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-minimal depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up irqbalance (1.1.0-2ubuntu1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Script virtuoso-nepomuk is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package irqbalance (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-standard:
 ubuntu-standard depends on cron; however:
  Package cron is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-standard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsolid4:
 libsolid4 depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsolid4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkio5:
 libkio5 depends on libsolid4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libsolid4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkio5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkemoticons4:
 libkemoticons4 depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkemoticons4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkpimtextedit4:
 libkpimtextedit4 depends on libkemoticons4 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libkemoticons4 is not configured yet.
 libkpimtextedit4 depends on libkio5; however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkpimtextedit4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkpimutils4:
 libkpimutils4 depends on libkemoticons4 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libkemoticons4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkpimutils4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkpimidentities4:
 libkpimidentities4 depends on libkio5; however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libkpimidentities4 depends on libkpimtextedit4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libkpimtextedit4 is not configured yet.
 libkpimidentities4 depends on libkpimutils4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libkpimutils4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkpimidentities4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libakonadi-kde4:
 libakonadi-kde4 depends on libkio5; however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libakonadi-kde4 depends on libsolid4 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libsolid4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libakonadi-kde4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkabc4:
 libkabc4 depends on libkio5; however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkabc4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkcal4:
 libkcal4 depends on libkabc4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libkabc4 is not configured yet.
 libkcal4 depends on libkio5; however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libkcal4 depends on libkpimutils4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libkpimutils4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkcal4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libakonadi-kcal4:
 libakonadi-kcal4 depends on libakonadi-kde4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libakonadi-kde4 is not configured yet.
 libakonadi-kcal4 depends on libkcal4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libkcal4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libakonadi-kcal4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libakonadi-contact4:
 libakonadi-contact4 depends on libakonadi-kde4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libakonadi-kde4 is not configured yet.
 libakonadi-contact4 depends on libkabc4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libkabc4 is not configured yet.
 libakonadi-contact4 depends on libkio5; however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libakonadi-contact4 depends on libkpimutils4 (= 4:4.14.10-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package libkpimutils4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libakonadi-contact4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of alsa-base:
 alsa-base depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package alsa-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libknewstuff3-4:
 libknewstuff3-4 depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libknewstuff3-4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkparts4:
 libkparts4 depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkparts4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libktexteditor4:
 libktexteditor4 depends on libkparts4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkparts4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libktexteditor4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkatepartinterfaces4:
 libkatepartinterfaces4 depends on libkio5 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libkatepartinterfaces4 depends on libknewstuff3-4 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libknewstuff3-4 is not configured yet.
 libkatepartinterfaces4 depends on libkparts4 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libkparts4 is not configured yet.
 libkatepartinterfaces4 depends on libktexteditor4 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libktexteditor4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkatepartinterfaces4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of katepart:
 katepart depends on libkatepartinterfaces4 (= 4:4.14.3-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libkatepartinterfaces4 is not configured yet.
 katepart depends on libkio5 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 katepart depends on libkparts4 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libkparts4 is not configured yet.
 katepart depends on libktexteditor4 (>= 4:4.14.2); however:
  Package libktexteditor4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package katepart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdoctools:
 kdoctools depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kdoctools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkde3support4:
 libkde3support4 depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libkde3support4 depends on libkparts4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkparts4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkde3support4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkdewebkit5:
 libkdewebkit5 depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libkdewebkit5 depends on libkparts4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkparts4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkdewebkit5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkfile4:
 libkfile4 depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libkfile4 depends on libsolid4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libsolid4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkfile4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkhtml5:
 libkhtml5 depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libkhtml5 depends on libkparts4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkparts4 is not configured yet.
 libkhtml5 depends on libktexteditor4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libktexteditor4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkhtml5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdelibs5-plugins:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 kdelibs5-plugins depends on katepart; however:
  Package katepart is not configured yet.
 kdelibs5-plugins depends on kdoctools (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package kdoctools is not configured yet.
 kdelibs5-plugins depends on libkde3support4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkde3support4 is not configured yet.
 kdelibs5-plugins depends on libkdewebkit5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkdewebkit5 is not configured yet.
 kdelibs5-plugins depends on libkemoticons4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkemoticons4 is not configured yet.
 kdelibs5-plugins depends on libkfile4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkfile4 is not configured yet.
 kdelibs5-plugins depends on libkhtml5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkhtml5 is not configured yet.
 kdelibs5-plugins depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 kdelibs5-plugins depends
dpkg: error processing package kdelibs5-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libplasma3:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libplasma3 depends on libkdewebkit5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkdewebkit5 is not configured yet.
 libplasma3 depends on libkio5 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 libplasma3 depends on libknewstuff3-4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libknewstuff3-4 is not configured yet.
 libplasma3 depends on libsolid4 (= 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libsolid4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libplasma3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plasma-scriptengine-javascript:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 plasma-scriptengine-javascript depends on libkio5 (>= 4:4.9.95~); however:
  Package libkio5 is not configured yet.
 plasma-scriptengine-javascript depends on libplasma3 (>= 4:4.9.95~); however:
  Package libplasma3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plasma-scriptengine-javascript (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stoppingNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:
 cron
 initscripts
 procps
 udev
 mountall
 upstart
 initramfs-tools-core
 initramfs-tools
 brltty
 bluez
 cups-browsed
 cups-daemon
 samba
 winbind
 libnss-winbind:i386
 mysql-server-5.7
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 whoopsie
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup
 kbd
 console-setup-linux
 rsyslog
 ubuntu-minimal
 irqbalance
 ubuntu-standard
 libsolid4
 libkio5
 libkemoticons4
 libkpimtextedit4
 libkpimutils4
 libkpimidentities4
 libakonadi-kde4
 libkabc4
 libkcal4
 libakonadi-kcal4
 libakonadi-contact4
 alsa-base
 libknewstuff3-4
 libkparts4
 libktexteditor4
 libkatepartinterfaces4
 katepart
 kdoctools
 libkde3support4
 libkdewebkit5
 libkfile4
 libkhtml5
 kdelibs5-plugins
 libplasma3
 plasma-scriptengine-javascript
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I don't see any dependency errors. All those 'insserv' errors mean that many of your old sysvinit services do not tell the system when they should be started or stopped. You must reinstall the providing packages, or fix each file by hand. Might be easier to clean-install Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Try synaptic package manager, for dependency errors.